# how to fetch data from database using prepare and bind in PHP?

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to fetch my data from database using **prepare** statement in php and I don't understand what I'm doing wrong in this?

Here is my code :

```
<?php
$host="localhost";
$user="root";
$password="";
$db="simpleinvoicephp";

$conn=mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$db);



$sql="SELECT * FROM invoice_user";

$result=mysqli_prepare($conn,$sql);

mysqli_stmt_bind_param($result,$id);

mysqli_stmt_execute($result);

mysqli_stmt_fetch($result);

echo $id;


?>
```

Error:

```
This page isn’t workinglocalhost is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500
```

Anyone help me out with this problem?

Thak you

Comment: `mysqli_stmt_bind_param` is to bind variables to parameters in the SQL, you probably wanted `mysqli_stmt_bind_result`.

Comment: @NigelRen yeah I tried this too but isn't work.

Comment: If you are trying to bind the parameter as a query criteria, your query will need `WHERE id = ?`. Please clarify: _do you want to fetch all users and bind the result_, or _select a user by `id` column_?

Comment: I would recommend you to [read the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) about mysqli and prepared statements. It contains plenty of different examples. You should also check the web servers error log to get the more specific error message when you're debugging.